# i want to make label that contain QR code and text beside the QR code

Tags: c#

How to make label containing QR code and text? I had create a QR code and the text separately but the problem now is i want to combine both of them and place in one label to be shown.

Comment: What UI framework? Please add the tag for it. Can you also provide the code you have already, and state the problem you are having achieving your goal.

Comment: I already had a QR code in picture box and text in textbox, my problems is how to put both of them in a panel?